# Is there a rule how to punctuate adverbial modifiers of time in their front position?

Tags: punctuation

I have a couple of sentences from a *Macmillan* coursebook by *Malcolm Mann* and *Steve Taylore-Knowles* 2007 going like this:

> - **Once a week,** Helen watches a film at the cinema.
> - **In the evening,** Helen usually meets her friends for coffee.

Which makes me think that we should **always** use a comma if the adverbial modifier of time is used in its front position compared to its position at the end of the sentence.

Am I right in thinking this way?

Comment: *Yesterday, all my troubles seemed so far away ...* but *Yesterday I went to the store.*

Comment: I can't infer a rule here

Comment: The rule is that you can use either, but commas are preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The use of a comma is preferred here. [Here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_clauses.htm) is a set of examples of how adverbial clauses may fit into a sentence and [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_after_a_sentence_introduction.htm) are some time adverbial specific examples.

Comment: any references to reliable sources?

Comment: [Yes, there are many.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas_intro.htm) It is not *always* necessary, but it is preferred.

Comment: could you be so kind as to refer me to one of them at least?

Comment: @Yukatan I just did! Check the hyperlink.

Comment: @Yukatan [See also.](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=comma%20after%20adverbial)

Comment: they are mentioning adverbial clauses there.. i'm looking for an explanation about adverbial modifiers of time which aren't a clause as I take it..

Comment: @Yukatan "aren't a clause"? "Once a week," and "In the evening," are both clauses. They are adverbial clauses. They are adverbial clauses that modify time. They are adverbial modifiers of time. They are all the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17286/discussion-between-yukatan-and-lewis-heslop).

Comment: they say in the link that an adverbial clause should contain a subject and a verb, in the above mentioned cases there is none

Comment: @Yukatan It really doesn't matter too much. That kind of nitpickiness is just for introductory English. Anyone who considers themselves an enthusiast of the language would tell you that  adverbial clauses and phrases are interchangeable terms and neither require an actual verb, they are *adverbial* after all.

Comment: @LewisHeslop, Yukatan. I reckon Yukatan's completely right here. *Tomorrow* is not a clause in anyone's grammar.

Answer (score 2):

In general, introductory adjectival and adverbial phrases (and clauses) are separated by a comma.

Commas serve a few primary purposes: to clarify phrase and sentences structure, to indicate elements in a series, and to reflect natural speech patterns. When separating introductory phrases or clauses, they serve to clarify structure and reflect flow.

> When I was a lad, I served a term as office boy to an Attorney's firm.

The comma suggests a pause, as would naturally occur in the oral rendition. It also helps clarify that it is incidental to the main clause, *I served a term*. But this is a convention. In most printed versions of [Gilbert & Sullivan's](http://www.victorianweb.org/mt/gilbert/porter.html) ditty, the comma is omitted.

When the introductory adjective or adverb is a singly word, the use of a comma depends on the flow more than logic.

> Yesterday I went to the store.

A comma is not needed because, for most speakers, the sentence would flow without a pause.

> [Yesterday, all my troubles seemed so far away](http://www.metrolyrics.com/yesterday-lyrics-beatles.html)

The comma reflects a pause in the sentence. Is it necessary grammatically? No. But if you listen to the recording, you can hear the comma.

> [Once there was a silly old ram](http://www.metrolyrics.com/high-hopes-lyrics-frank-sinatra.html)

but

> Once upon a time, there was a silly old ram.

Comment: Absolutely. *Cadence* (in speech) is what counts, not *grammar* as such. If there's no spoken pause, you probably don't want a comma.